# How can I create both image captions and a image overlay with CSS?

Tags: css

Essentially I am trying to recreate the following items (on hover is the image to the right): [image]

Which is a screen shot from the following site: https://www.loungelizard.com/
There are a lot of  question that just deal with just creating an image overlay or a just an image captions so I thought I it would be a hybrid version of them both.

Here is the code I have so far:

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" class="desc_ImageOverlay">
    <img src="http://www.imagesource.com/Doc/IS0/Media/Home2/5/8/7/8/IS09AR776.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    <div class="desc">
        <p class="desc_content">Test</p>
    </div>
    <span class="OverlayText">
      <p> 
        This is some new test text. 
      </p>  
    </span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
 div.desc{
     bottom: 50%;
     color: #fff;
     left: 50%;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
}

.desc_content{
     color: orange;
     shadow:  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
     font-size:  20px;
}

.desc_ImageOverlay {
      width:140px;
      text-decoration:none;
      position:relative;
      display:block;
      border:1px solid #666;
      padding:3px;
      margin-right:5px;
      float:left;
}

.desc_ImageOverlay span.OverlayText {
        visibility:hidden;
        position:absolute;
        filter:alpha(opacity=50);
        -moz-opacity:0.5;
        -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
        opacity: 0.5;
}

desc_ImageOverlay:hover span.OverlayText{
        visibility:visible;
}
```

Any help trying to achieve the same result as this site would be appreciated. Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/pipsy17/pen/qNBYdj?editors=1100) that I currently using.

Comment: Two divs, one on top of another, filter:opacity the first on hover. I'll do a fiddle and post and answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
codepen.io/LordNeo/pen/EyxLXX
```

There is two divs positioned one on top of the other, on hover, the first one dissapears (opacity:0) revealing the bottom one.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.desc_ImageOverlay{
  text-decoration: none;
  position:relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:240px;
  background: none 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
.desc_ImageOverlay .desc{
  font: 16px/20px sans-serif;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding:24px 16px;
  transform: translateY(30%); -webkit-transform: translateY(30%);
  transition: 0.5s;           -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}
.desc_ImageOverlay .desc p{
  transition: 0.5s; -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  opacity:0;
}
/*hover*/
.desc_ImageOverlay:hover .desc{
  transform: translateY(0%); -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
  color: #000;
}
.desc_ImageOverlay:hover .desc p{
  opacity:1;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="desc_ImageOverlay" style="background-image: url(http://www.imagesource.com/Doc/IS0/Media/Home2/5/8/7/8/IS09AR776.jpg);">
  <div class="desc">
    <h2>STRATEGY</h2>
    <p> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum aliquid illo, repellat magnam veritatis mollitia eum itaque reiciendis esse
    </p>  
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#" class="desc_ImageOverlay" style="background-image: url(http://www.imagesource.com/Doc/IS0/Media/TR5/9/c/c/6/IS09AF3QC.jpg
);">
  <div class="desc">
    <h2>SAILING</h2>
    <p> 
       Consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum aliquid illo, repellat magnam veritatis mollitia eum itaque reiciendis esse lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>  
  </div>
</a>
```